# Python Telegram Bot delete_message (aiogram)

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I need to delete messages sent by the bot, and to achieve this I have to use the parameters `chat_id` and `message_id`.
For chat_id I easily use `message.chat.id`
, but I don't know how to get `message_id`

If I use
`bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello!')`

How can I get `message_id` from this message, or how can I delete it

Comment: according to the [telegram api](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage) the send message function returns an `updates` value, which you can use to get the message id

Comment: great, ill put this into an answer

Answer (score 2):

according to the [telegram api](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage) the send message function returns an updates value, which you can use to get the message id